# Getting token (JWT) error in MERN stack task manager

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, jwt, mern

I am building a goal setter app in MERN using JWT. I've done the creating and deleting goals, however, I am getting a token error with the update tasks function. It's pretty much the same as deleting goals, getting the goals._id. Here's what my code looks like:

Update and delete goal slice (note that delete one works)

```
 // Update goal

export const updateGoal = createAsyncThunk(
  "goals/update",
  async (id, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      const token = thunkAPI.getState().auth.user.token;
      return await goalService.updateGoal(id, token);
    } catch (error) {
      const message =
        (error.response &&
          error.response.data &&
          error.response.data.message) ||
        error.message ||
        error.toString();
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(message);
    }
  }
);



// Delete goal
export const deleteGoal = createAsyncThunk(
  "goals/delete",
  async (id, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      const token = thunkAPI.getState().auth.user.token;
      return await goalService.deleteGoal(id, token);
    } catch (error) {
      const message =
        (error.response &&
          error.response.data &&
          error.response.data.message) ||
        error.message ||
        error.toString();
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(message);
    }
  }
);
```

goalService.js

```
const updateGoal = async (goalId, token) => {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
  };
  const response = await axios.put(API_URL + goalId, config);

  return response.data;
};


the front-end

     function GoalItem({ goal }) {
      const dispatch = useDispatch();
      const [editing, isEditing] = useState(false);
      const onSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
    
        dispatch(updateGoal(goal._id))
        
      };
      return (
        <>
          <div className="goal">
            <div>{new Date(goal.createdAt).toLocaleString("en-US")}</div>
            <h2>{goal.text}</h2>
            <button
              onClick={() => dispatch(deleteGoal(goal._id))}
              className="close"
            >
              X
            </button>
            <button onClick={() => isEditing(true)} className="btn-sml">
              Edit
            </button>
            {editing && (
              <section className="form">
              <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
                <div className="form-group">
                  
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    name="text"
                    id="text"
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                     <button className="btn btn-block" type="submit">Update goal</button>
                </div>
              </form>
            </section>
            )}
          </div>
        </>
      );
    }
```

```
// @desc Update goal
// @route PUT /api/goals/:id
// @access Private
const updateGoal = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const goal = await Goal.findById(req.params.id)

  if(!goal) {
    res.status(400)
    throw new Error('Goal not found')
  }

 
  // Check for user
  if(!req.user) {
    res.status(401)
    throw new Error('User not found')
  }
  // Make sure the logged in user matches goal user
  if(goal.user.toString() !== req.user.id){
    res.status(401)
    throw new Error('User not authorized')
  }
  
  const updatedGoal = await Goal.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, {new:true,})

  res.status(200).json(updatedGoal);
});
```

Comment: can you provide your backend code? and the error you are getting.

Comment: sure, assuming you are asking for controllers?

Comment: Can you try logging value of req.user.id and provide your authorization code and error. Is there any github repo or something I can refer to get full code?

Comment: here's the repo https://github.com/livinginatent/mern-tutorial

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: My bad, it was set private. Now changed, should be accessible

Answer (score 1):

In your repo. You have passed config as second argument which is for data in goalService.updateGoal.

```js
const response = await axios.put(API_URL + goalId, config);
```

Change this to

```js
const response = await axios.put(API_URL + goalId, null ,config);
```

Also you are using ReactDOM.render which is not supported in react 18
Use `createRoot`

```js
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
// other imports
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render([...])
```

Comment: Thanks, did the changes and the initial problem is resolved, no more token issue. However, now when I update the goal with a new name, all existing tasks get removed from the UI and only reappear after refreshing the page. I will now work on that but thanks once again !